# How to use Async with Angular8 firestore in ngOnInIt function?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving data from firestore in the ngOnInIt function and trying to use that data in that same lifecycle. How to use Async to solve the problem?

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUserData().subscribe(actionArray =>{
      this.userList = actionArray.map(item =>{
        console.log("Items", item);
        console.log("Data : ", item.payload.doc.data());
        return {
          id : item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as customersUser;
      })
    });
    console.log("User List : ", this.userList);
    
    this.getUserData();

  }
  
  
  
  getUserData(){
  this.userList.map(item =>{
    if(item.id == this.userId){
      this.userObj = item;
    }
  })
  console.log(this.userObj);
}
```

I am receiving an empty array of userList[] since the function does not wait to receive snapshot changes.

Answer (score 2):

Move this line

```
    console.log("User List : ", this.userList);
```

to where the `userList` is populated with data, that is, inside the subscriber. So, instead of

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUserData().subscribe(actionArray =>{
        this.userList = actionArray.map(aMappingFunction);
    });
    console.log("User List : ", this.userList);

    this.getUserData();
  }
```

do

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUserData().subscribe(actionArray =>{
        this.userList = actionArray.map(aMappingFunction);
        console.log("User List : ", this.userList);
    });

    this.getUserData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [async await](https://javascript.info/async-await). It's another solution. try it.

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.service.getUserData().subscribe(actionArray =>{
      this.userList = actionArray.map(item =>{
        console.log("Items", item);
        console.log("Data : ", item.payload.doc.data());
        return {
          id : item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as customersUser;
      })
    });
    console.log("User List : ", this.userList);

    await this.getUserData();

  }



  getUserData(){
  this.userList.map(item =>{
    if(item.id == this.userId){
      this.userObj = item;
    }
  })
  console.log(this.userObj);
}
```